# search for text of textview android

Tags: android, textview

I have a textview that render a large amount of text and I want search in this text and scroll the textview to it

is there any method in the textview allow me to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there's no such a direct method, but here's some way I would use to achieve it:

1. Use [getLayout()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#getLayout()) method of a `TextView` to get access to layout.
2. Find offset for a text you're searching.
3. Find the line for this offset using [getLineForOffset()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout#getLineForOffset(int)) method.
4. Use [getLineTop()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout#getLineTop(int)) to find the top coordinate of this line.
5. Knowing top line coordinate and position of the view itself, compute the scroll offset.

Comment: Thanks a lot , it helps me a lot

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail Did you achieve a result and could you please share the code? Thanks.